# Calculate the compression progress in SharpZipLib c# and the compression time

Tags: c#

I am using the following code in order to zip files from folder in c# code.

```
public void zipFile(){

    try 
    {
        // Only get subdirectories that begin with the letter "p."
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path+dataDir);
        //print(path+dataDir);
        Console.WriteLine("The number of directories starting with p is {0}.", dirs.Length);
        foreach (string dir in dirs) 
        {
            outName = dir+".zip";
            FileStream fsOut = File.Create(outName);
            ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(fsOut);
            zipStream.SetLevel(7);

            int folderOffset = dir.Length + (dir.EndsWith("\\") ? 0 : 1);

            try{

                CompressFolder(dir, zipStream, folderOffset);
                zipStream.IsStreamOwner = true; // Makes the Close also Close the underlying stream
                zipStream.Close();
            }
            catch(IOException e){

                UnityEngine.Debug.Log (e.Message);
            }
            catch(OutOfMemoryException e){

                UnityEngine.Debug.Log (e.Message);
            }

            Directory.Delete(dir, true);        
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        print("The process failed: {0} " + e.ToString());
    }


}
```

The code searches for folders in dir and zip them one by one. I ve got two questions to made. Firstly why the performance of the compression is not comperable with winrar? I am using SharpZipLib. Is there so much difference in both libraries? If yes is there any suggestion in order to improve the compression speed? Secondly how can I calculate the compression progress inside the foreach?

Comment: Eugene Roshal is an extraordinarily good programmer, very few people can do what he does.  Getting a progress callback from a compression algorithm is pretty hard to come by, you'll have to guestimate it by number of files and file size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly why the performance of the compression is not comperable with winrar?

RAR and ZIP are two different algorithms, as you have rightly observed. AFAIK RAR is proprietary for compressing and free for decompressing. ZIP is in public domain - free to use. There are other differences of course.

Generally, however, there is a trade off between compression speed and compression ratio. ZIP is really good for compression ratio (it compresses text data extremely well), but it is also one of the slowest algorithms you can pick.

Have a look at a few other general compressors: LZMA, LZO, Snappy, LZ4. The last two are blazing fast, but generally won't compress data as well as Lempel-Ziv variants.

> Secondly how can I calculate the compression progress inside the foreach?

You can first count the number of files or folders that you need to compress - this is your `max` variable. In the loop use a `current` counter that you increment every iteration. Then `(current / (double)max) * 100)` gives you percent completed.

Also as per @Hans Passant comment you can include size of the files to get more accurate result.

Comment: Thus rar is a faster algorithm that zip. I just thought that they had approximately the same performance. I am trying to compress binary data which correspond to kinect video streams.

Comment: There's probably a better codec for that. Binary, including video, is notoriously difficult to compress. Have a look at dedicated video compressors, maybe H.264 or MPEG variants. You can probably get much higher compression ratio if you can use lossy compression, but that only can work if you can tolerate some quality loss.

Comment: I ve already performed a kin of h.264 compression in my stream. However what I am wandering is why winrar windows application compress the file faster thatn SharpZipLib zip approach?

Comment: Because it's a different proprietary algorithm for which you may need to pay license fee. It can be faster on particular data and slower on other. If you are after speed, consider using LZ4 or Snappy. But bare in mind, you cannot keep compressing data, at some point you'll hit a wall when your compressing will only eat up CPU and won't reduce size of a file. Doing more compression after this point will only increase CPU load and size of the file. Usually, you'd want to use only 1 algorithm, so  if you are already using H.264 variant - you are probably already doing maximum you can.

Comment: I accidentally found [Brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) recently open-sourced by Google, might be worth giving it a go. Although it's in C and C++ maybe there is a port for C# somewhere